# Limits simple question

Tags: limits, functions

I have this function: $f(x)=\begin{cases}{x^2\cos(\frac{1}{x}),\text{if x$\neq$0}}\\{2},\text{if x=0}\end{cases}$
and I want to find the $\lim_{x\to0}{f(x)}$. Which of the two forms of $f(x)$ I use?

Comment: Recall that the limit as $x$ approaches a value $a$ considers values that are close to $a$ but *are not equal to* $a$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should use is the case $x\neq0$.

<strike>Because the limit of $\cos(\frac1x)$ does not exist when $x$ approaches to $0$, therefore the limit of $f(x)$ does not exist when $x$ approaches to $0$.</strike>

Recall the definition of limit:

> The limit of function $f(x)$ at point $x=c$ exists, if $x$ approaches $c$ resulting $f(x)$ approaches a point $L$.
>
> We then denote this PHENOMENON as $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=L$.

The definition of limit is an active PHENOMENON, not evaluating the function at point $c$.

**APPROACH a point does not mean AT that point.**

Now back to your problem.

Because $x^2\cos(\frac1x)$ approaches $L=0$ as $x$ approaches $c=0$, therefore $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=0$.

Comment: The first sentence is correct, but the second one (“limit of $f(x)$ does not exist”) isn't. (The multiplication by $x^2$ makes a big difference!)

Comment: ohh, I missed the $x^2$, thx~ @HansLundmark